# MDX - Getting the last 6 month Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, dimension

I have a Dim table that called `DimAccounts`. 
It is describing a User account and the dates that the account has been created. 
for Example:

[image]

I would like to get the list of accounts that have been created on the last 6 month Dynamically. For example today is the 09\01\2016.
So my list of accounts will be the accounts created from the `01-08-2015` until `09-01-2016`. Notice that this `CreatedOn` field does not have a hierarchy and it is an attribute of the accounts dimension .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have properly set the ValueColumn property of your CreatedOn attribute in your dimension (so that MemberValue comes back a date data type) then the following should work:

```
select {[Measures].[Your Measure Here]} on 0,
[DimAccounts].[AccountPK].[AccountPK].Members on 1
from [Your Cube]
where {
 Filter(
  [DimAccounts].[CreatedOn].[CreatedOn].Members
  ,[DimAccounts].[CreatedOn].CurrentMember.MemberValue > DateAdd("m",-6,Now())
 )
}
```

Or if you want to create a named set so that any user can just drop it on rows, put this in the calculations tab of your cube designer:

```
CREATE SET CurrentCube.[Accounts Created In Last 6 Months]
as
Exists(
 [DimAccounts].[AccountPK].[AccountPK].Members,
 Filter(
  [DimAccounts].[CreatedOn].[CreatedOn].Members
  ,[DimAccounts].[CreatedOn].CurrentMember.MemberValue > DateAdd("m",-6,Now())
 )
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! ,
My solution was to add a flag column to the table that will show 1 if an account created in past 6 month or not.
your solution Helps me a lot also :)